# Laptop battery indicator saying "plugged in, not charging"

Tags: windows, windows-vista, battery, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba Satellite with Windows Vista is a couple years old.

The battery lately is completely shot. Even after charging for a long time, it barely lasts five minutes when you unplug it. I'm assuming it's related to this new problem.

Anyway, the last couple days it's been saying "plugged in, not charging", and it's down to 0% now. I've already tried taking out the battery and reinstalling the battery in device manager. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

If the laptop is several years old, the battery is probably at the end of its service life.

Every laptop user runs into this issues after some years. Buy a replacement battery.